# Using PHP to determine a user can handle FancyZoom (Javascript image zoomer)

Tags: php, javascript

I'm working on a small PHP-driven website that's so basic that I can't imagine a browser from any time in the 2000's, if not further back, would have any serious issues with it.

I added the FancyZoom Javascript image viewer, though, and it's the ONE part of my site that I can't bet my life on in terms of across-the-board compatibility, especially taking fragmented mobile browsers into account (for instance, I'm still using an iPhone 3GS, so I know luddites like me are out there).

I know browser/feature detection is discussed here often, but I've got a relatively specific request since I'm not an up-to-date web programmer. What specific features (or user agents, if the case may be) should I be detecting to determine whether to enable an image viewer like FancyZoom or simply leave the user with a direct image link?

I'd imagine that it should be possible to filter out a few cases where the image loader wouldn't work, without going so far as to use one of those uber-complex user agent parsers that require updates, etc. This is a really simple, specific detection problem.

Any ideas on how to boil this down to the simplest possible features to check for would be great. Thanks!

Comment: If you use javascript [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) you usally don't need browser detection. So if the user has disabled javascript the site should work, too. And with javasript you do a progressive enhancement.

Answer (score -1):

you could do something like this to weed out old browsers

```
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 

if(preg_match('/(?i)MSIE [1-6]/',$browser) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$browser))
 {
$image = 'Non fancy zoom';

} else

{
$image = 'fancy zoom';
}
```

I have not messed with the jquery plugin your using, so I do not know what browsers it is good for etc, but you can use the below to find their browser and just write rules...

```
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Comment: ...and then Opera updates to support all the required javascript features, and the script still won't work in Opera, because you decide to not serve it based on the user-agent string. Deactivating features based on user agent identification is evil. Never do it. Use Javascript to detect if certain objects/methods are available, and handle the fallback functionality on the Javascript level when necessary.

Comment: I am not picking on Opera or any other browsers… That is just an example. I am not a Java expert and do not claim to be. If I knew a certain browser had issues, I would return a static image this way (because it is what I know), so my site would not look bad for that user. 
I always like learning something new that I do not do every day. Could you post a quick example of doing this in JavaScript, so I and he can have it for reference?

Comment: Let's say you have a feature which requires the rather new [Javascript Geolocation API](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html). This feature is accessed with the global object `navigator.geolocation`. When a browser has this object, you can assume that it supports geolocation. So you would add the javascript code `if (typeof navigator.geolocation != 'undefined') {'` and activate the functionality in that if-block.

Comment: A javascript library which makes it much easier to add such feature checks is [Modernizr.js](http://modernizr.com/)